# Intercept multiple keyboard symbols

Tags: autohotkey, intercept

Is there any way to output the upper symbol characters on my 2nd keyboard i mean when i press shift + 2 on my 2nd keyboard it'll output "@" and it will gets read by autohotkey, whenever i press shift + 2 it's either output LShift or 2

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want? At the moment, it sounds like you want to remap Shift+2 to something. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i'd like to use shift + 2 on autohotkey using intercept on my 2nd keyboard, but it doesn't work when i put "+2::" on ahk script and it seems that intercept only reads LShift and 2 when i'm pressing shift+2(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "intercept on my 2nd keyboard"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
AutoHotInterception (AHI).
HIDMacros
LUA Macros

I've used HIDMacros in the past. AutoHotKey still doesn't properly support multiple keyboards unfortunately.